# Grails invalid stream header: 00000000

Tags: java, grails, serialization

The problem is that I have my domains with relations but I can't call a object with `findAll`. When I do I get `invalid stream header: 00000000`, and when I debug and evaluate the variable my debugger can not deserialize.

The domains that I use are:

```
class CMovimientoTransaccion {

    CMovimiento movimiento
    Number posicion
    String descripcion
    CEstatus estatus
    Date fechaAlta = new Date()
    Date fechaBaja

    static belongsTo = [CMovimiento, CEstatus]

    static constraints = {
        movimiento(blank:true, maxSize: 200)
        estatus(blank: true)
        estatus(nullable: true)
        fechaAlta(display:false)
        fechaBaja(display:false, nullable: true)
    }

    String toString() {
        "${movimiento ?: ''} ${descripcion ?: ''} "
    }
}

class CMovimiento {

    String movimiento
    String tipo
    CEstatus estatus
    Date fechaAlta = new Date()
    Date fechaBaja

    static hasMany = [cMovimientoTransaccions: CMovimientoTransaccion]

    static constraints = {
        movimiento(blank:true, maxSize: 200)
        estatus(nullable: true)
        fechaAlta(display:false)
        fechaBaja(display:false, nullable: true)
    }

    String toString() {
        "${movimiento ?: ''} ${tipo ?: ''} "
    }
}

class CEstatus {

    String estatus
    Date fechaAlta = new Date()
    Date fechaBaja

    static hasMany = [cMovimientoTransaccions: CMovimientoTransaccion]

    static constraints = {
        estatus(blank:true, maxSize: 200)
        fechaAlta(display:false)
        fechaBaja(display:false, nullable: true)
    }

    String toString() {
        "${estatus ?: ''} "
    }
}
```

And the service is:

```
def obtenerMovimientoTransaccion() {
    CMovimientoTransaccion cMovimientoTransaccion = CMovimientoTransaccion.get(0)

    cMovimientoTransaccion
}
```

That service is call by a controller  MovimientosService:

def guardarUsuariosEvaluacion(){
CMovimientoTransaccion cMovimientoTransaccion = movimientosService.obtenerMovimientoTransaccion()

cMovimientoTransaccion 
}

The trace is :

```
Line | Method
->>  804 | readStreamHeader                  in java.io.ObjectInputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    299 | <init>                            in     ''
|     24 | $tt__obtenerMovimientoTransaccion in MovimientosService.groovy
|     80 | guardarUsuariosEvaluacion         in PlazaVacanteController.groovy
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . .  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter                          in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                               in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I see in my project and when I call other domain the same trace is show. I donw know If that is for the domain and the relations o is the problem with the implements serializable

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exception that gets thrown when findAll() gets called?

Comment: I add in the question, thanks!!!

Comment: And what's in the controller around line 80 and the service around line 24?

Comment: The controller is the line that call the service  MovimientosService to the function obtenerMovimientoTransaccion() I was see and in other calls to domain show me the same mistake,